# Using Facebook Messenger Share things

Tags: objective-c

When I use FBSDKShareKit to share specific string with Facebook Messenger, everything is fine, however, if I push the back button to original app, like this

[image]

Next time I want to use Facebook Messenger to share specific string, the Facebook Messenger will show nothing.

[image]

```
    FBSDKShareMessengerURLActionButton *urlButton = [[FBSDKShareMessengerURLActionButton alloc] init];
    urlButton.title = @"Free AD WiFi";
    urlButton.url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.adwifi.com.tw/"];

    FBSDKShareMessengerGenericTemplateElement *element = [[FBSDKShareMessengerGenericTemplateElement alloc] init];
    NSString *userShareCodeString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userInviteNum"];
    if ([userShareCodeString isEqualToString:@""] | (userShareCodeString == nil)) {
        element.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"12673"];
    }else {
        element.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", userShareCodeString];
    }
    element.subtitle = @"FreeADWiFi, Amazing!";
    element.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.adwifi.com.tw/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/%E8%AA%A0%E5%93%81-01-1.png"];
    element.button = urlButton;

    FBSDKShareMessengerGenericTemplateContent *content = [[FBSDKShareMessengerGenericTemplateContent alloc] init];
    content.pageID = @"";
    content.element = element;

    FBSDKMessageDialog *messageDialog = [[FBSDKMessageDialog alloc] init];
    messageDialog.delegate = self;
    messageDialog.shareContent = content;

    if ([messageDialog canShow]) {
        [messageDialog show];
    }


    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)options {

    return [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                               sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                      annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]] | [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:app
                                                                                                                                                     openURL:url
                                                                                                                                           sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                                                                                                                                  annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
                                                                                                       ];;
}
```